# Nature of force on electron in atom

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, nuclear-physics

what is the nature of force on electron in atom .Is it coulombic or electromagnetic force?
As electron is in random motion so we cannot take it as electrostatic force. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: Electrons are not in motion, at all. You are simply applying an unworkable semi-classical mental model to a system that does not have classical motion properties.

Answer (score 3):

The electron is a quantum mechanical entity as well as the atom. One cannot describe the atom in terms of classical mechanics and electrodynamics.

In particular , the coulomb potential enters in [the quantum mechanical wave equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydsch.html#c2) and the solutions of that equation describe the orbitals that tie up the electron with the nucleus and create the bound atom. [These are the solutions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html) for the hydrogen atom.

It is not simple and needs a course on quantum mechanics.